# Remove a corrupted file in a Linux system

Tags: filesystems, hardware, files, ext2

How to remove a file that is corrupted?

In Linux (Fedora based), when I type: `ls -l` I get

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 dmiller3 dmiller3     4096 Jul 26 13:57 SomeFile
??????????   ? ? ?                   4096 Jul 26 13:57 CorruptedFile
```

I can't do anything with this CorruptedFile. I can't use it in delete or anything. It's the only file in the entire system that is like this. What causes this, and how can I remove it?

File system is ext2.

Comment: I removed the 'Fedora' tag because this isn't really specific to your distro

Comment: Have you tried running `fsck` on the unmounted partition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could have been writing to a file during a hard reset, or your hard drive could have problems. a `fsck` should fix it (you will have to `umount` the fs to do this). I'd check `dmesg` and `smartctl -a /dev/hdx` (latter is part of smartmontools ) to see if your HD is reporting any errors. I'd also run a non-destructive `badblocks` on the partition.

You should also ask yourself why you are running ext2, because journaling tends to help with these kinds of problems.

Comment: Thanks. Reason why we use ext2 is because it came from the vendor this way. It's a custom distro based on Fedora for embedded systems. You solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Some entertaining problems with filesystems I've seen were:

- A file that only shows up when asked for specifically: "ls file" shows it, but a plain "ls" doesn't. What happened is that the next file had the escape sequence for "Go up a line" in its name
- Files with impossible permissions/type: Fixed by a fsck(8), or just blowing the file away with rm(1)
- Very deep directory tree, created by a miscreant creating directories and cd'ing into them in a loop: Had to write a program that went down to the end, and then backed up deleting a directory in a loop.