# Unix - Delete folder with strange characters using inode or similar

Tags: directory, inode, special-characters, delete

I want to remove this folder : 
Name Name 1x05 name FormaciÃ³n

I have tried all I have seen on internet :

```
find -maxdepth 1 -inum INODE_NUMBER -exec rm -i {} \;
rmdir: wrong deleting './Name Name 1x05 name FormaciÃ³n': don't exist file or folder
```

Too I tried to use mc (Middnight Commander) , Krusader and any other methods I have seen on internet.

But is not posible. Give this problem.

We can enter in folder and to rename parent but we can't rename or delete this folder.

The problem is because is a folder with spaces and wrong chars and is not posible to change it. You can enter on folder but you can't remove or rename.

So is not duplicated. There is not any solution for this case on StackSchange.

I think the only solution would be edit directly inode to make renaming and be able to remove later, but I don't know how to do on Unix system.

System is Ubuntu but I suppose would be in any other system.

Any method to delete this folder or to edit directly folder name ?

Thanks.

Comment: @Christopher: It is highly unlikely that that will work.

Comment: @Christopher: Yes, it works if having spaces in the file name *is the only problem*.   The `rmdir: wrong deleting './Name Name 1x05 name FormaciÃ³n': don't exist file or folder` error message says that the problem is bigger than that.

Comment: @Ricardo: You say “We can enter in folder”.  What do you mean by that?  Obviously you are using the command-line interface; i.e., the shell.  Can you ``cd`` *into* the bad directory?  Can you rename the bad directory?  Do ``ls -laR`` from the parent directory and post the output in your question. Do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: See also [Remove a corrupted file in a Linux system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1511/80216).

Comment: Is this directory mounted on a network share of some description?

Comment: Is a folder, not a file. Is not duplicated question. Yes i can enter on folder but I can't rename or delete it due to strange chars. File System is not corrupted, the problem is because is a folder, so you can't delete searching as an inode.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the filesystem is corrupted.

If it's a root filesystem you may have to boot to single user mode first, if it's not root filesystem you should stop all the processes that access it and unmount it.

Then figure out what block device it is (e.g. `/dev/sdb1` or `/dev/mapper/something`) and run `fsck /dev/that/device`.

If you can provide the output of `mount` (just like that with no parameters) and highlight which mount point contains the affected directory I can come up with a more detailed plan.